# Prevent people from downloading / copying / making a copy of data in Google doc

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Is there a way to share a Google Document in view-only mode with someone but prevent them from downloading it, copying and pasting the data, printing it, or going to `File > Make a copy`?

I understand that if they really wanted to they could also take a screen shot and then OCR the image, but that's a little bit more technical, so I'm not sorry worried about people doing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just added: [Disable downloading, printing, and copying of any Google Drive file](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/07/disable-downloading-printing-and.html)

From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893)

> If you don’t want your file to be widely shared, you can disable the option to download, print, or copy it. When someone with view or comment permissions opens the file, these options will be disabled.

[image: screen shot]

(h/t [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/google-drive-now-lets-you-block-downloading-or-copying-1717942323))

Comment: (PDF can be set up to prevent copy-paste, but this can be bypass easily, or at least used to be last time I faced the issue, by cracking Adobe security e.g. http://www.ehow.com/how_6785425_copy-paste-secure-pdf.html or at worst OCR, although the OP indeed assumes that readers don't have IT skills)

Answer (score -3):

You can restrict access with http://www.flashpanel.com/pricing/, but I can't work out whether I need to order minimum 200 licences or not. If you find out the answer post on here please?

Comment: How does Flashpanel restrict downloads?