# Prevent editors from being able to make a copy of the spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I do not want people with edit access to be able to make a copy of the spreadsheet. Is it possible to do that? I know how to prevent people with only viewing access to do that but how do I do the same to editors?

Answer (score 3):

The only option for editors is to block them from changing permissions. You cannot stop them from making a copy.

You can learn more about owner options [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893?authuser=1&p=disable_download&hl=en&rd=1#disable).

You may also want to take a look at some of the workarounds [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/prevent-people-from-downloading-copying-making-a-copy-of-data-in-google-doc).

Answer (score -1):

You can use IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet you never share","range") for a critical bit of information in a spreadsheet you share, for example...